# how to redirect to twitter home page after authentication of twitter in android

Tags: android, android-layout

hi in my appliction i want to redirect page to home page of twitter .I took web view and in that webview i gave url  "http://twitter.com/home?status=" but it is going to default my login page who might be logged in.It is going to my home page itself.please help me how to redirect to home page after twitter authentication.
       this is my web view code

```
        browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);
    browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    browser.loadUrl("http://www.twitter.com?status=");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check callback url of browser when you authenticated then it redirects to home page. Use this,

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new TwitterWebViewClient());

private class TwitterWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Redirecting URL " + url);

        if (url.startsWith(CALLBACK_URL)) {
            browser.loadUrl(TWITTER_HOME_URL);              
            return true;
        }  else if (url.startsWith("authorize")) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) { }
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) { }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { }
}
```

Comment: no i want the url for twitter home page i gave the url "http://www.twitter.com?status=" but after login it is sending msgs to whom logged in but showing home page of mine